# Java - which objects exist in PSOldGen?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is there a way to see which objects exist in the OldGen part of the heap? I know how to see all objects in the heap (jmap), but I want to see only the object in the PSOldGen.

Is there a way to do so?

Edit: Explanation about my problem & need

My application needs very big heap (it is used in production with -XmX30G).
We have issues that every ~20 minutes, the application hangs for ~20 seconds due to full garbage collection. I would like to see what are the objects that survive enough time to move to the Old gen, and only then get garbage collected.
Which approach should I take?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to use good profiling tool like  [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) or [Jprobe](http://www.quest.com/jprobe/) to have a deeper look to your heap. You can check the objects which are not getting garbage collected and occupying the heap. Object which does not get collected slowly keeps on moving to old gen space. You cant check the object age and can identify objects which has higher age would be in Old gen space.

Comment: How do I see this in JProfiler? how do i see object age? which object move to old gen?

Comment: You have to read vendor specific guide to see it, however most of them comes with sleeky UI which gives all these information.

Answer (score 0):

What's your issue? Having bigger heap size or longer GC pauses?

If it's about higher heap size, you can inspect the objects in heap just after a full GC with jmap and check if you need them all. If there are extra objects which you are still referring to, you can change the code accordingly.

If your issue is due to longer GC pauses, you can take jmap output before and after a full GC and see the difference of those outputs which should give details of what objects were garbage collected in that cycle. You can trace the origin of those objects creation and avoid that, may be by object pooling or so.